# Does NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding make a byte array

Tags: ios, md5, utf-16, nsstringencoding

I need to encrypt a string.  The service that I am sending it to requires that it be an MD5 hash of the byte array of the string in UTF16LE.

Basically: if I have `myString` that needs to be put into a UTF16LE byte array, and then that array needs to be MD5 Hashed.

Does NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding actually make the byte array?  I can't tell from the documentation if that's what is going on.
If it does not, does anyone have a good way to create a byte array form a sting with UTF16LE encoding?
I've tried using `getBytes`, and [myString bytes] and `const char` and I still am striking out.  Admittedly there is something I don't understand but the documentation @dev.apple is not shedding any light that I can see.
Note: I asked a similar question the other day but I have since found out more information about what they want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will when you use it with `-[NSString dataUsingEncoding:]`:

```
NSData * data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
const char* const bytes = data.bytes;
```